# Push Docker image to Gitlab Registry when repository have two Docker images (client and server)

Tags: docker, gitlab, docker-registry

I have a Gitlab Repository that hosts a web app made with React / NodeJS, So, I have the client and server in the same repo.

App is working, and I want to use Gitlab Registry my Docker images (client and server).

Thing is my repository has the name: `gitlab.com/group/project`

And it is expecting a Docker image with the same name.

Instead, I have two Docker images:

- registry.gitlab.com/group/project_api
- registry.gitlab.com/group/project_client

So, it won't let me push my images. I get:

> denied: requested access to the resource is denied

How can I do it ? I don't want to make two repositories.

Comment: Ah, you are trying to push them to the same registry. You _could_ use different tags, but it is not recommended - it is more standard to create two GitLab projects. The syntax for using tags would be `gitlab.com/group/project:api` (and `:client` for the client, obviously).

Comment: In general the tag is for versions, so to use them for two separate streams of work is a bit of a misuse. However, it will work... `:-p`

Comment: I get : denied: requested access to the resource is denied

Comment: What is the exact `docker push` command you are using? As per my advice above, you need to push a registry that exists, and that needs to be the built name of the image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I could solve it using:

```
docker push registry.gitlab.com/group/project/api
docker push registry.gitlab.com/group/project/client
```

Here is what it looks like in the UI:

[image]

As specified in the [relevant gitlab documentation chapter](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/container_registry.html#build-and-push-images), you can use up to three levels for your images names:

- `registry.gitlab.com/group/project:tag`
- `registry.gitlab.com/group/project/image1:tag`
- `registry.gitlab.com/group/project/module1/image1:tag`

Comment: I've not seen that syntax before. Would you add a screenshot of what that looks like in the GitLab UI? Do these appear in the same registry?

Comment: Yep, let me push both images.

Comment: I get it from https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/container_registry.html#build-and-push-images

Comment: @halfer screenshot uploaded

Comment: Ah nice, I didn't know GitLab could do that. I need to fix some of my own projects `:-D`

Comment: @halfer. per [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/container_registry.html#build-and-push-images), you can use up to 3 levels for your images name, e.g. `project:tag`, `project/image1:tag` or `project/module1/image1:tag`

Comment: @Zeitounator: nice! I've been using a registry per image (and its past versions) thus far.

Comment: @halfer yes, it would be quite unconfortable for microservices in a single repo